# Force command to be run on logout or disconnect?

Tags: ssh, logout

I'm logging in to a system via SSH and I'd like to be able to force a command to be run on logout, whether that's an intentional logout (exiting the shell) or because my SSH connection has dropped/been terminated.  Is there any way to set this up?  My best guess right now is to change the login shell to a program that intercepts the signal sent on SSH closing (SIGHUP?) and executes the command then, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner solution.

Comment: Do you want to execute the command on the remote-machine or on the one you initialized the connection from?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to use [pam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluggable_authentication_module).

In `/etc/pam.d` you will have several files, one of them will be called `sshd`. If you only want to affect ssh, and not other logins (such as a GUI, or real TTY), you want this file.
If you want to affect all logins, you'll want a 'common' file. The name of this other 'common' file varies by distro, but you can track it down by following the `include` and `substack` statements in the `sshd` file until you get to the base file.

Once you've identified the file in `/etc/pam.d` that you want to use, add a line such as the following to the `session` section:

```
session     optional    pam_exec.so quiet /etc/pam_session.sh
```

This will result in calling `/etc/pam_session.sh` every time someone logs in and logs out (whether gracefully or ungracefully).

Now you just need to create `/etc/pam_session.sh`. Below is an example you could use to run something every time someone logs out:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$PAM_TYPE" = "close_session" ]; then
  something
fi
```

*(don't forget to `chmod a+x` the script)*